# Edited photos have reverted to originals on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I edited about 20 photos on my phone yesterday -- cropped, altered saturation and contrast etc. This morning, on my phone, those edits have all reverted to the original photos.

I use iCloud library. The photos had not completed uploading to iCloud library before I edited them. My phone uses ios 11.3

Can these edits be recovered now that iCloud sync up is complete and those edits are reverted to the original photos?

EDIT: given that there is no solution, and that others report the same problem (and that it happened again), I have filed a bug report at Apple:

https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=40326889

Comment: I also have this same issue, after updating to the new IOS 11.3 last night on my iPad, I have lost all the photos over the last 4 weeks. Hundreds of edits photos have been reverted back to the originals in a matter of seconds. Not happy at all. And there doesnt seem to be any solution, other than not buying a Apple product next time.

Comment: My iphone is doing the same thing. i keep re-editing the photos but after midnight they all revert back to the original photo. any idea how to stop this from going on?

Comment: This is extremely annoying and must be a bug in the iOS software. Even the portrait function is removed... :( Any solutions to the problem?

Comment: Have also been having this problem with iOS 11.3 - 11.4.

Comment: I cannot believe there are so few people reporting this error. We suffer from this defect everyday with iOS 11.4

Comment: And I cannot open the link with Apple bug report. It says "We're sorry, something went wrong." Yeah right, that one statement sums today's Apple really well in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Assuming you don't get any of the "long shots" below to work, you'll have to re-crop and re-edit the photos from the originals.

Photos keeps only two versions of an image by design - the original photo and the current edited version. Other apps like Aperture save undo and redo actions and perform non-destructive edits, but not Photos or the iCloud photo library.

Unless your phone still has those images cached and would upload them, you likely lost the edits.

Here are the "long shots" for looking:

1. Look in the **Recently Deleted** Album (online and on your device and optionally on another synced device if you should have them)
2. Look for upload paused on the iPhone (scroll to the bottom of the content on the **All Photos** Album
3. Check for iOS backups after you made the edits - you might be able to restore that backup and interrupt the iCloud download of the non-edited versions.